# R memory issues for extremely large dataset

Tags: r

I need to perform regression analysis on a 3.5gb dataset consisting mixed (numerical and categorical) dataset in CSV format consisting of 1.8 million records and 1000 variables/columns mainly containing 0s and 1s and a few categorical and numeric values. (Refer snapshot of data.)

I was initially supposed to directly perform clustering on this dataset but I kept getting a lot of errors related to memory in spite of running it on a remote virtual machine (64-bit Windows Server 2012 R2) having 64gb RAM.  So I thought of doing some factor analysis to find correlation between the variables so that I can reduce the number of columns to 600 - 700 (as much possible). Any other ideas are appreciated as I am very naïve to data analysis.

I have tried various packages like ff, bigmemory, biganalytics, biglm, FactoMineR, Matrix etc but with no success. Have always encountered “cannot allocate vector of size …” or reached maximum allocation of size 65535MB some other errors.

Can you guys let me know of a solution to this as I feel memory should be a problem as 64gb RAM should suffice. 
Snapshot of dataset:

```
SEX AGE Adm Adm     LOS DRG DRG RW  Total   DC Disp Mortality   AAADXRUP
M   17  PSY         291 887 0.8189  31185    PDFU         0           0
M   57  PSY ER       31 884 0.9529  54960.4  SNF          0           0
F   23  AC  PH        3 775 0.5283  9497.7   HOM          0           0
F   74  AC  PH        3 470 2.0866  23020.3  SNF          0           0
```

There are additional columns after Mortality mostly containing 0s or 1s

Comment: 65535MB  is roughly 65.5 Gb. Memory is a problem.

Comment: So how much memory do you think would be required as the current data is only 3 months old and I may need to process 6 month or a year old data which will be twice or four times the size of the current 3.5Gb dataset.